# IIS url redirect from non-www to www not working

Tags: redirect, iis

I have this rewriting rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force non-WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.yourdomainname.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It successfully redirects *example.com* to *https://example.com*, however, I need redirection to *https://www.example.com*, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,just limit the domain or you want dynamic domain?

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Force non-WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www.(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

use the match all and the negate to redirect

Comment: Yes, I also want dynamic domain too. And will your rule work with https redirecting?

Comment: you also want if no www append?

Comment: i have change the rule please try

Comment: I've tried, but this rule doesn't redirect from non-www to www.